# Testing the Text to Slack RestComm Application

Tags: java, voip, mobicents, restcomm

I'm testing the Text to Slack app from RestComm Application Store http://apps.restcomm.com/downloads/text-to-slack-2/

Couple comments :

1. There is some problems in the description of installation the application. In "Quick quide Step 2" : it says "Before you proceed with the configuration guide, you must get a Mailgun authentication key. Follow the steps below" but no MailGun is required, only the slack configuration is needed to be setup.
2. in "Test Your App" : it says "MAKING A CALL TO YOUR APPLICATION" and talk about SIPPhone but the application is using text only not calls so making a call to the application results in nothing happening and the call being disconnect. It would be great to have instructions on how to test messaging from a SIP Phone.

Comment: Also when I try to use the application with the built in webrtc, It seems it fails with a 500 when trying to reach Slack for some reason : 09:00:37,830 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.model.steps.es.ExternalServiceStep] (http-/10.111.187.218:8080-6) Requesting from url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
09:00:37,942 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.model.steps.es.ExternalServiceStep] (http-/10.111.187.218:8080-6) Remote service failed with: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error

Comment: I found the solution. I was using the wrong format for the channel in the configuration. I was using general instead of #general. Works great now !

Answer (score 0):

Jean,

Thank you for notifying. There was an issue with the application post. The older blog post replaced the new one somehow. I am trying to find why is that occuring.

Text To Slack is an SMS application. You can only test it by registering SMS enabled DID. You can only send SMS messages from US number for now. In step 3 (Test your app) it is described that it is necessary.

The actual description of the app is now available on RAS.

Comment: It seems the description (step 3) still talks about MAKING A CALL TO YOUR APPLICATION instead of SMS.